# Why does cloning my custom type result in &T instead of T?

Tags: reference, rust, cloning

```
use generic_array::*; // 0.12.3
use num::{Float, Zero}; // 0.2.0

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Vector<T, N: ArrayLength<T>> {
    data: GenericArray<T, N>,
}

impl<T, N: ArrayLength<T>> Vector<T, N>
where
    T: Float + Zero,
{
    fn dot(&self, other: Self) -> T {
        self.data
            .iter()
            .zip(other.data.iter())
            .fold(T::zero(), |acc, x| acc + *x.0 * *x.1)
    }

    fn length_sq(&self) -> T {
        self.dot(self.clone())
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:21:18
   |
21 |         self.dot(self.clone())
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Vector`, found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `Vector<T, N>`
              found type `&Vector<T, N>`
```

Why does this happen? Why does `clone` return `&T` instead of `T`?

Why does this work if I implement `Clone` myself?

```
use generic_array::*; // 0.12.3
use num::{Float, Zero}; // 0.2.0

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vector<T, N: ArrayLength<T>> {
    data: GenericArray<T, N>,
}

impl<T: Float, N: ArrayLength<T>> Clone for Vector<T, N> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Vector::<T, N> {
            data: self.data.clone(),
        }
    }
}

impl<T, N: ArrayLength<T>> Vector<T, N>
where
    T: Float + Zero,
{
    fn dot(&self, other: Self) -> T {
        self.data
            .iter()
            .zip(other.data.iter())
            .fold(T::zero(), |acc, x| acc + *x.0 * *x.1)
    }

    fn length_sq(&self) -> T {
        self.dot(self.clone())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You get this error when your type doesn't implement `Clone`:

```
struct Example;

fn by_value(_: Example) {}

fn by_reference(v: &Example) {
    by_value(v.clone())
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:6:14
  |
6 |     by_value(v.clone())
  |              ^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Example`, found &Example
  |
  = note: expected type `Example`
             found type `&Example`
```

This is due to the auto-referencing rules: the compiler sees that `Example` doesn't implement `Clone`, so it instead tries to use `Clone` on `&Example`, and immutable references always implement `Clone`.

The reason your `Vector` type doesn't implement `Clone` is because [the derived `Clone` implementation doesn't have the right bounds on the type parameters (Rust issue #26925)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925).  Try explicitly writing `self.dot(Self::clone(self))` to get an error message along these lines.

See also:

- [Deriving a trait results in unexpected compiler error, but the manual implementation works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39415052/155423)