# Deriving a trait results in unexpected compiler error, but the manual implementation works

Tags: rust, clone

This code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=76d81c07dffb995b91a86487fd5b5ed4&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo<'a, T: 'a> {
    t: &'a T,
}

fn bar<'a, T>(foo: Foo<'a, T>) {
    foo.clone();
}
```

... does not compile:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `clone` found for struct `Foo<'a, T>` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:16:9
    |
3   | struct Foo<'a, T: 'a> {
    | ---------------------
    | |
    | method `clone` not found for this
    | doesn't satisfy `Foo<'_, T>: std::clone::Clone`
...
16  |     foo.clone();
    |         ^^^^^ method not found in `Foo<'a, T>`
    |
    = note: the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `T: std::clone::Clone`
            which is required by `Foo<'_, T>: std::clone::Clone`
help: consider restricting the type parameter to satisfy the trait bound
    |
3   | struct Foo<'a, T: 'a> where T: std::clone::Clone {
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Adding `use std::clone::Clone;` doesn't change anything, as it's already in the prelude anyway.

When I remove the `#[derive(Clone)]` and manually implement `Clone` for `Foo`, it **compiles as expected**!

```
impl<'a, T> Clone for Foo<'a, T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Foo {
            t: self.t,
        }
    }
}
```

What is going on here?

- Is there a difference between `#[derive()]`-impls and manual ones?
- Is this a compiler bug?
- Something else I didn't think of?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The answer is buried in the error message:

> ```
>     = note: the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
>             `T: std::clone::Clone`
>             which is required by `Foo<'_, T>: std::clone::Clone`
> ```

When you derive `Clone` (and many other automatically-derived types), it adds a `Clone` bound on **all** generic types. Using `rustc -Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded`, we can see what it becomes:

```
impl <'a, T: ::std::clone::Clone + 'a> ::std::clone::Clone for Foo<'a, T> {
    #[inline]
    fn clone(&self) -> Foo<'a, T> {
        match *self {
            Foo { t: ref __self_0_0 } =>
            Foo{t: ::std::clone::Clone::clone(&(*__self_0_0)),},
        }
    }
}
```

In *this* case, the bound is not needed because the generic type is behind a reference.

For now, you will need to implement `Clone` yourself. [There's a Rust issue for this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925), but it's a comparatively rare case with a workaround.

Comment: There is also an [RFC for extending `#[derive]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2353)

Comment: There is a crate for this: [`derivative`](https://crates.io/crates/derivative).

Answer (score 4):

Your example will derive `Clone` without any problems if you explicitly mark that `T` should implement `Clone`, like this:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo<'a, T: 'a> {
    t: &'a T,
}

fn bar<'a, T: Clone>(foo: Foo<'a, T>) {
    foo.clone();
}
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=236396791c635a9424379cff0aef6ad9&version=stable&backtrace=0))

It seems unusual that you can avoid specifying the bound explicitly, but Shepmaster's answer seems to suggest that the compiler inserts it implicitly, so my suggestion is functionally identical.

Comment: This is a good solution, but I disagree with *functionally identical* — in this case, the struct can only contain a `T` that implements `Clone`, but that particular bound isn't **required** to clone a reference. If the program requires `T` to be cloned for other reasons, this works.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that `T: ::std::clone::Clone + 'a` from your example meant that `T` implemented `Clone` anyway; am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Shepmaster, after some testing I've found that you can remove the `Clone` bound on `T` in the struct without problems, and by doing that I produce exactly the same output from the expanded pretty printer as the manual `impl`.

Comment: No, that's my fault for being unclear. I meant that my "solution" is to implement `Clone` without deriving it. That allows the structure to not have the restriction at all.