# Conditionally implement a Rust trait only if a type constraint is satisfied

Tags: rust, generic-programming

I have the following struct:

```
pub struct Foo<T> {
    some_value: T,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Self { some_value: value }
    }
}

// Implement `Default()`, assuming that the underlying stored type
// `T` also implements `Default`.
impl<T> Default for Foo<T>
where
    T: Default,
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new(T::default())
    }
}
```

I would like `Foo::default()` to be available if `T` implements `Default`, but *not* available otherwise.

Is it possible to specify "conditional implementation" in Rust, where we implement a trait if and only if some generic type trait constraint is satisfied? If the constraint is not satisfied, the target trait (`Default` in this case) is not implemented and there is no compiler error.

In other words, would is it possible to use the generic struct above in the following way?

```
fn main() {
    // Okay, because `u32` implements `Default`.
    let foo = Foo::<u32>::default();

    // This should produce a compiler error, because `Result` does not implement
    // the `Default` trait.
    //let bar = Foo::<Result<String, String>>::default();

    // This is okay. The `Foo<Result<...>>` specialisation does not implement
    // `Default`, but we're not attempting to use that trait here.
    let bar = Foo::<Result<u32, String>>::new(Ok(42));
}
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a **specific problem or error** and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself.* — This code is not even syntactically valid Rust code, thus it fails with a syntax error. Additionally, you haven't included the complete error message, so we don't know what error you might have been experiencing.

Comment: @Shepmaster My apologies. In hindsight, this question wasn't very well thought out. I've amended the syntax errors and added extra clarification to the question.

I've selected Kornel's post as the accepted answer, but will also edit the original question post to confirm that it is indeed possible with the code I've specified.

Comment: I've updated the question to include extra explanation of @Kornel's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Kornel's answer, it turns out the compiler *already* conditionally implements traits of generic structs.

The `Default` trait is only implemented for `struct Foo<T>` if `T` satisfies the type constraints specified when defining the implementation of `Default`. In this case, the constraints were defined as `where T: Default`. Therefore, `Foo<T>` only implements `Default` if `T` implements `Default`.

As shown by the `fn main()` example above, any attempt to use the `Foo<T>`'s `Default` implementation when `T` does not implement `Default` produces a compiler error.

Answer (score 6):

For this specific instance, the implementation provided by `derive(Default)` does exactly what you've asked for:

```
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Foo<T> {
    some_value: T,
}
```

See also:

- [Deriving a trait results in unexpected compiler error, but the manual implementation works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39415052/155423)

Answer (score 3):

Your example, after fixing minor syntax issues, does work:

```
pub struct Foo<T> {
    some_value: T,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Self { some_value: value }
    }
}

// Implement `Default()`, assuming that the underlying stored type
// `T` also implements `Default`.
impl<T> Default for Foo<T>
where
    T: Default,
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new(T::default())
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dc2e32f9a72337877c00229e73996ea3&version=stable)