# How to implement a mutable cactus stack in Rust?

Tags: tree, rust, stack

A  [Cactus Stack or Parent Pointer Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parent_pointer_tree) is a stack where nodes in the stack have pointers to their parent so the stack is climbable in multiple ways.

I'm trying to implement a mutable Cactus Stack in Rust based off of [this immutable implementation](https://github.com/softdevteam/cactus) using the `Rc<RefCell<T>>` pattern to pass around shared memory:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[derive(Clone, Default)]
pub struct Cactus<T> {
    node: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Node<T> {
    val: Rc<RefCell<T>>,
    parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    len: usize,
}

impl<T> Cactus<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Cactus<T> {
        Cactus { node: None }
    }

    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.node.is_none()
    }

    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.node.as_ref().map_or(0, |x| x.borrow().len)
    }

    pub fn child(&self, val: T) -> Cactus<T> {
        Cactus {
            node: Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
                val: Rc::new(RefCell::new(val)),
                parent: self.node.clone(),
                len: self.node.as_ref().map_or(1, |x| x.borrow().len + 1),
            }))),
        }
    }

    pub fn parent(&self) -> Option<Cactus<T>> {
        self.node.as_ref().map(|n| Cactus {
            node: n.borrow().parent.clone(),
        })
    }

    pub fn val(&mut self) -> Option<Rc<RefCell<T>>> {
        self.node.map(|n| n.borrow_mut().val.clone())
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_simple() {
        let r = Cactus::new();
        assert!(r.is_empty());
        assert_eq!(r.len(), 0);
        assert!(r.val().is_none());
        assert!(r.parent().is_none());
        let r2 = r.child(2);
        assert!(!r2.is_empty());
        assert_eq!(r2.len(), 1);
        assert_eq!(*r2.val().unwrap(), 2);
        let r3 = r2.parent().unwrap();
        assert_eq!(r3.is_empty(), true);
        assert_eq!(r3.len(), 0);
        let r4 = r.child(3);
        assert_eq!(r4.len(), 1);
        assert_eq!(*r4.val().unwrap(), 3);
        let r5 = r4.parent().unwrap();
        assert!(r5.is_empty());
        let r6 = r4.child(4);
        assert_eq!(r6.len(), 2);
        assert_eq!(*r6.val().unwrap(), 4);
        assert_eq!(*r6.parent().unwrap().val().unwrap(), 3);
    }    
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=841bf9facae571d2030aa4a51ef8dc12&version=undefined)

My issue is getting the `val` from nodes:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:64:9
   |
64 |         assert_eq!(*r2.val().unwrap(), 2);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::cell::RefCell`, found integral variable
   |
   = note: expected type `std::cell::RefCell<{integer}>`
              found type `{integer}`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:70:9
   |
70 |         assert_eq!(*r4.val().unwrap(), 3);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::cell::RefCell`, found integral variable
   |
   = note: expected type `std::cell::RefCell<{integer}>`
              found type `{integer}`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:75:9
   |
75 |         assert_eq!(*r6.val().unwrap(), 4);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::cell::RefCell`, found integral variable
   |
   = note: expected type `std::cell::RefCell<{integer}>`
              found type `{integer}`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:76:9
   |
76 |         assert_eq!(*r6.parent().unwrap().val().unwrap(), 3);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::cell::RefCell`, found integral variable
   |
   = note: expected type `std::cell::RefCell<{integer}>`
              found type `{integer}`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
```

Comment: Why do you need different implementation? Use immutable `Cactus` with elements of type `RefCell<T>` or `Rc<RefCell<T>>`.

Comment: Typo. You forgot `as_ref`.

Comment: What are you using `Rc` for? Do you really want a single *value* to be shared between multiple nodes?

Comment: The code in the Playground link does not reproduce the error message in the question.

Comment: @red75prime I will try that, I hadn't thought of that, thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid that you lost yourself here by just trying to throw `Option`, `Rc` and `RefCell` at the issue.

Those are not cure-all, you need to understand when they make sense, and when they don't.

Here is the revised definitions I arrived at:

```
pub struct Cactus<T>(Option<Rc<Node<T>>>);

struct Node<T> {
    value: RefCell<T>,
    parent: Cactus<T>,
    len: usize,
}
```

*Disclaimer: I have tried to infer where you actually need mutability, and where you don't, since you never actually explained it. My inference may have been incorrect in places; for example I decided that switching parents was unnecessary.*

Let's analyze `Node`:

1. `Node` uniquely owns it value, it *never* shares it, therefore there is no point for `Rc` here.
2. `Node` may be aliased, and yet you still want to modify its value, this requires wrapping the value in a `RefCell`.
3. `Node` *always* has a parent, because `Cactus` already embeds a concept of nullity.

and `Cactus`:

1. `Cactus` may be null, so it's an `Option`.
2. `Cactus` shares its node with others, so `Rc` is required.
3. `Cactus` never needs to switch to another `Node`, it can directly mutate the shared node instead, so `RefCell` is unnecessary.

From there, we can implement `Clone` for `Cactus` ([the automatic derivation fails hard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39415052/155423)):

```
impl<T> Clone for Cactus<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self { Cactus(self.0.clone()) }
}
```

Note the use `as_ref` to obtain a `&Rc` in the lambda; without it, the `map_or` call would try to move the `Rc` out of `self.0` which is forbidden because `self` is borrowed.

The other functions follow as naturally:

```
impl<T> Cactus<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Cactus<T> { Cactus(None) }

    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool { self.0.is_none() }

    pub fn len(&self) -> usize { self.0.as_ref().map_or(0, |n| n.len) }

    pub fn child(&self, val: T) -> Cactus<T> {
        let node = Node {
            value: RefCell::new(val),
            parent: self.clone(),
            len: self.len() + 1,
        };
        Cactus(Some(Rc::new(node)))
    }

    pub fn parent(&self) -> Cactus<T> {
        self.0.as_ref().map_or(Cactus(None), |n| n.parent.clone())
    }

    pub fn value(&self) -> Option<&RefCell<T>> {
        self.0.as_ref().map(|n| &n.value)
    }
}
```

Note that I changed a few signatures:

1. `parent` returns `Cactus`, which may be null. I do not make the difference between having a null parent and being null; this is questionable, I just felt that having a possibly null `Cactus` wrapped in an `Option` was bizarre.
2. `value` returns a reference to `RefCell` (wrapped in `Option`), so that the caller can call `borrow_mut` and mutate the actual value.

This required a few adaptations to the tests:

```
#[test]
fn test_simple() {
    let r = Cactus::new();
    assert!(r.is_empty());
    assert_eq!(r.len(), 0);
    assert!(r.value().is_none());
    assert!(r.parent().is_empty());

    let r2 = r.child(2);
    assert!(!r2.is_empty());
    assert_eq!(r2.len(), 1);
    assert_eq!(*r2.value().unwrap().borrow(), 2);

    let r3 = r2.parent();
    assert_eq!(r3.is_empty(), true);
    assert_eq!(r3.len(), 0);

    let r4 = r.child(3);
    assert_eq!(r4.len(), 1);
    assert_eq!(*r4.value().unwrap().borrow(), 3);

    let r5 = r4.parent();
    assert!(r5.is_empty());

    let r6 = r4.child(4);
    assert_eq!(r6.len(), 2);
    assert_eq!(*r6.value().unwrap().borrow(), 4);
    assert_eq!(*r6.parent().value().unwrap().borrow(), 3);
}
```

Mostly, as you can see, calling `.borrow()` after `.unwrap()`.

Of note, the latest line fails to compile: `r6.parent()` returns a temporary value out of which we attempt to obtain a reference; the compiler complains that this reference is used after the temporary is dropped, probably as a detail of how `assert_eq` is implemented.

> ```
>    |
> 74 |         assert_eq!(*r6.parent().value().unwrap().borrow(), 3);
>    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>    |         |           |
>    |         |           temporary value created here
>    |         temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
>    |
>    = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
>    = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
>    = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
> ```

Simply replacing `r6.parent()` by `r4` fixes this issue.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Much nicer indeed.

Comment: @Shepmaster: It's still a pity that `Clone` cannot be auto-derived; or at least, that the auto-derive introduces a `T: Clone` requirement that is unnecessary since `T` is behind a `Rc`. A limitation of a syntax-based derive, I am afraid. A semantic-based one could realize that `impl Clone for Rc` does not require such bound.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering so quickly and thoroughly! What a great answer, this definitely solved my problem.