How to clone enum class with trait bound in Rust
I'm writing a calculator application in Rust, which has an Action enum class describing either an operation or a value:
#[derive(Clone)]
enum Operation<W: Write> {
    ValueNone(fn() -> MyResult<Value>),
    ValueOne(fn(Value) -> MyResult<Value>),
    ValueTwo(fn(Value, Value) -> MyResult<Value>),
    ValueAll(fn(Vec<Value>) -> MyResult<Value>),
    EngineNone(fn(&mut Engine<W>, &mut W) -> MyResult<bool>),
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
struct Value {
    number: Option<BigRational>,
    meaning: Meaning,
    comment: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
enum Action<W: Write> {
    Operation(Rc<Operation<W>>),
    Value(Value),
}

The Operation::EngineNone enum value is intended to encapsulate operations like "show stack" or "show help".
For various reasons, I would like to clone an action in certain situations:
fn apply_action<W: Write>(action: Action<W>) {
    let action = action.clone();
    ...
}

However, this results in a compiler error:
error[E0599]: the method `clone` exists for enum `Action<W>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/engine.rs:33:25
   |
33 |     let action = action.clone();
   |                         ^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Action<W>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
  ::: src/action.rs:12:1
   |
12 | pub enum Action<W: Write> {
   | ------------------------- method `clone` not found for this enum because it doesn't satisfy `Action<W>: Clone`
   |
note: trait bound `W: Clone` was not satisfied
  --> src/action.rs:11:10
   |
11 | #[derive(Clone)]
   |          ^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced in this `derive` macro
help: consider restricting the type parameter to satisfy the trait bound
   |
32 | fn apply_action<W: Write>(action: Action<W>) where W: Clone {
   |                                              ++++++++++++++

I cannot implement the suggested change, because I am passing a std::io::Stdout object, which does not implement Clone.  However, I do not understand why a W needs to be cloneable here, because I am not storing it anywhere in Action, merely passing it to the function defined in the Operation::EngineNone enum value.
Can anyone (i) explain why Rust is complaining here, and (ii) suggest a workaround?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415052/deriving-a-trait-results-in-unexpected-compiler-error-but-the-manual-implementa. Manually implement Clone or use the derivative crate with a custom bound.
